# Wordpress - Disqus error with custom page template

Tags: javascript, wordpress, cdata, disqus

I created a custom page template to display a filterable portfolio in Wordpress.
However, on that custom page I am getting an error code -

```
// <![CDATA[ (function() { document.write('<script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript" src="http://thinquetanque.disqus.com/get_num_replies_from_wpid.js?v=2.2&amp;t=span&amp;wpid0=14&amp;wpid1=1"><' + '/script>'); })(); //]]>
```

I think this might be because the page uses a loop to display posts. And Disqus is set to only display on posts.

See the page at: http://thinquetanque.com/portfolio

Any ideas on how to prevent this?

thanks!

EDIT: I found the spot in the code where this is happening - but I don't know how to resolve the error.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[
    (function() {
        document.write('<script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo dsq_js_comment_count_url().$post_id_str; ?>"><' + '/script>');

    })();
//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: I can't see the error - one 404 from Twitter, but that's not what you mean? The javascript gets loaded, but what do you want to achieve there? Display the current comment count? Because then you need a span with a `dsq-postid` id.

Comment: The error code appears right below the thumbnails - and I don't want disqus, comment counts, etc. on this page. The page is set with comments off, however because disqus automatically integrates itself into wordpress, I think it's trying to make a call here.

Comment: and it only appears to be happening on firefox - I don't see the text on chrome or IE -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, when using theme frameworks - such as hybrid, or in my case, canvas - there is some sort of issue with the following bit of disqus code:

```
add_action('loop_end', 'dsq_loop_end');

function dsq_js_comment_count_url() {
    return 'http://'.strtolower(get_option('disqus_forum_url')).'.'.DISQUS_DOMAIN.'/get_num_replies_from_wpid.js?v=2.2&t=span'; }
```

I removed it from disqus.php on line 726.
and voila - problem solved.

Comment: I think some javascript code adds `display: block` to your `<script` tag. This makes the disqus code visible. I don't think the error comes from Disqus, but from something else you use to get this layout.